# Serialize Sequence[T] when I have a correct JsonFormatter for T

Tags: scala, spray, spray-json

I'm trying to write a function that will dump a list of `NbaPlayerBoxScore` to a json file. I have written a `JsonFormat` function which is able to serialize `NbaPlayerBoxScore` to the file. However, I want to write a `Seq[NbaPlayerBoxScore]` to the file. Here is my attempt

```
def dumpToJsonFile(contents : Seq[NbaPlayerBoxScore], protocol : JsonFormat[NbaPlayerBoxScore]) : Unit = {
      import protocol._
      val w = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName))
      w.write(contents.toJson.prettyPrint)
      w.close
    }
```

and here is the error I get:

```
[error] /home/chris/dev/nba-api/src/main/scala/io/extrapoint/nbaapi/models/NbaPlayerBoxScoreDAO.scala:174: Cannot find JsonWriter or JsonFormat type class for Seq[io.extrapoint.nbaapi.models.NbaPlayerBoxScore]
[error]       w.write(contents.toJson.prettyPrint)
[error]                        ^
[error] one error found
```

How can I serialize a sequence of `NbaPlayerBoxScore` when I have a correct formatter for a single `NbaPlayerBoxScore`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up solving my issue right after I posted this question. I used a implicit parameter for the formatter and then imported `DefaultJsonProtocol`

Here is the solution:

```
def dumpToJsonFile(contents : Seq[NbaPlayerBoxScore])(implicit protocol : JsonFormat[NbaPlayerBoxScore]) : Unit = {
  import DefaultJsonProtocol._
  val w = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName))
  w.write(contents.toJson.prettyPrint)
  w.close
}
```